# Codeigniter - sessions seems to vanish? v2

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, frameworks

Can anyone explain from this simple login script why the session seems to delete itself?
The is no destroying of sessions anywhere so I cannot see why it does this?

http://pastebin.com/sunXhSEE

Comment: Do you have enough space on the hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check whether sessions are enabled in the first place;
- Check for session_start();
- Check if the session gets set correctly by echo'ing $_SESSION directly, not using the framework accessors.

Comment: Not sure if it helps... but the legacy app was running Codeigniter v1.5 (really old I know) and i'm updating it to run on the latest version (2.1.2)
Everything seems to work except the sessions - I can see the sessions ok within the function auth by doing a var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())

But using $_SESSION doesn't work (but using the framework method does) however when the redirect the user_level variable always return FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter by default doesn't use the $_SESSION PHP variable, it implements it's own. So that's why $this->session->all_userdata() will return all the data correctly, but $_SESSION won't return anything relevant.

See here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html the note:

> Note: The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers.